# Firebase Firestore - Performance of multiple simultaneous read queries on a single collection with billions of documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have built an App that let's users determine the presence of a document in a collection via a cloud function. As of now everything works fine and it takes less than a second to determine whether the document belongs to the collection, time mostly spent executing the cloud function. However, I have questions about scalability and performance:

1. Is this architecture scalable for millions of users trying to read the same collection for different documents at the same time?
2. I understand that NoSQL is fast,but how long would a search to determine the presence of a document take among 1 billion of them? Any simple rule of thumb relating latency with collection size  for a read query without data retrieval would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, Firestore scales massively.
2. The time to fetch 1 document in 1 million is the same as the time to fetch 1 document in 1 trillion.  The size of the collection doesn't matter in terms of read performance.  What matters is the number of documents you're querying.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply! This is the best news.